# Employer wanting to show employee pay on a board for everyone to see

Tags: salary, united-states, ethics

Is it legal and/or ethical to show employee pay information on a screen for everyone to see?

The scenario:

- Company wants to increase productivity in an hourly warehouse environment
- Wants to move to a "piecework" model
- Pay a rate per piece of "something" they process
- Example: Employee A processed 500 widgets. They get a 50cents a widget. They make $250.
- They would make a base rate of min wage + the "piecework" amount.

The employee wants to then post everyone "piecework" amount for the day on a board for eveyone in the warehouse to see. I guess to "motivate" people and foster competition???

Comment: Legal questions require a jurisdiction. Where is this an issue?

Comment: In the USA. Multiple states including CA, NC, NY +  PA

Comment: And are they displaying pay or merely the number of pieces (which is a factor of pay, but not pay itself)?

Comment: I believe they want to show the $ amount.

Comment: Ethics questions come up a lot here without seeming like the OP has thought through their question.  What ethical principal in particular are you concerned this may contradict?  Do you think this is unfair in that some can outperform others?  Do you think this oversteps on right to privacy?  Do you think this shows lack of concern for wellbeing?

Comment: @Myles "Ethical concerns" is code for "me no like- please agree this bad".

Answer (score 2):

So if employees want to share their pay information, this is legal; in fact, to suppress the sharing of pay information is illegal.

IMO, and IIRC from PM Coursework in school... To put into place a model like this is poor organizational management.  That concept is how elementary school fundraisers are run, something like a book reading competition, where waste and endangerment are non-issues.  Unless this is the utmost unskilled task labor, completion with no aspect of quality, the pay scale leaves no room for organization improvement or knowledge sharing between employees either.

Comment: Not to mention it can quickly lead to employees agreeing, beetwen themself, on X amount a day as a 100% productivity benchmark while being able to make 2X but having a very strong position in negotioation. Plus it can lead to Work-to-rule or malicious compliance

Comment: This answer tells us that it is legal for *employees* to share their salaries voluntrily, but it does not answer the actual question: Is legal for *employers* to share the salaries of all employees *without their individual consent*? Further, the question doesn't just ask about publishing wages, but also about publishing productivity data of individual employees, which is a whole different problem.

Comment: And the information about under which circumstances this may lead to an improvement and under which it is harmful might also be interesting background-information, but it's not what the question asked for. The question asks "is it legal" and "is it ethical".

Comment: @Philipp Re-read the question.  The employer is not posting salary information, they are posting a scoreboard of how many widgets each employee is making a day.  Whether anyone can derive pay from that information is not the employer's problem.

Comment: @Jack I read the question enough times already, thank you. This answer still does not answer the question "Is it legal and/or ethical"

Comment: @Philipp publishing metrics of employee output to other employees is not illegal or unethical in any country on this earth as far as I know.  How do you think ranking in the sales departments work? "Bob just made $10 million in sales this month.  Joe made 8 million.  These two are employees of the month!"

Comment: @Jack Comments are not meant for answering questions. If that is your answer to this question, please post it as a new answer.

Comment: This answer addresses a different question than what the OP asked and then adds on a bonus opinion.  But it’s not an answer to this question.

Comment: You assert that suppressing the sharing of pay information is illegal.  Where are you getting that?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it legal..

That depends entirely on where you live and work. Google is your friend here.

> ... and/or ethical.

As long as they are only revealing "piecework" totals - and not base salary - then I'd say it's perfectly ethical. It's completely transparent - it takes something that is a definite and quantifiable measure of productivity and is using it to reward the most productive workers.

In addition, it will incentivize employees. Somebody leaving the shop floor at the end of a week can see that, if they'd matched Bob's work rate, they could have come out with an extra $100. That's giving them a definite and, more importantly, achievable goal. They know it's achievable because Bob just did it.

That's far preferable to somebody sitting behind a desk, plucking a number out of thin air, and saying "*you should be able to do 800 of these a week*" - that carries zero weight since he/she isn't making widgets all day.

Whether they post the number of units or the $ value makes no difference - everybody knows the unit rate and can calculate one from the other.

For what it's worth I run a few teams and am responsible for assigning annual bonuses from an assigned pot of cash. It's only logical the best performers should get the highest bonus - dividing the money equally is unfair to those who worked their butts off all year. Unfortunately I work in software development where it's difficult to quantify productivity or value to the company (there are ways, but they are either game-able or too subjective - lines of code, bugs raised/fixed etc.). This scheme is a perfect way to both improve productivity and ensure those who do the most work get better rewards.

The only potential problem I see is that, in the rush to churn  out as many widgets as possible, quality may take a tumble.

Comment: In a physical manufacturing environment rush to produce widgets could also have safety implications along with quality risks.

Comment: You seem to imply that posting base salary would *not* be ethical.  Why not?  In most cases, companies try to suppress base salary information to limit the information their workers have to argue salary from, but I've not seen anything that would suggest that it was an ethics thing.

Comment: Didn't intend to imply that.. i was going to touch on base salary but edited as the answer was getting too long. Possibly not edited well enough if remnants suggest I believe it entirely unethical! I think it's a grey area - ethical in the sense that everything is transparent and laid out bare for all to see. (Of course it's for that very reason , as you've mentioned, that companies DON'T reveal this information). It may not be ethical in the sense that it should be up to individual employees if they want to reveal that information.